# is the Superellipse function convex or not?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem and i need to know if the following constraint of Superellipse is convex or not

$\left|\frac{x-x_o}{a}\right|^n  + \left|\frac{y-y_o}{b} \right|^n \geq 1$

where $x$ and$y$ are variables, {$x_o$ ,$y_o$} are constants, and  {a,b,n} are positive constants.

Thanks

Comment: With $\ge 1$ this is _never_ a convex subset of $\mathbb R^2$ for _any_ $n$, since $(x,y)=(x_0\pm a, y_0)$ are always in the set but the midpoint between them, $(x_0,y_0)$, is not.

Comment: Sorry, what about being a convex subset of $R^6$??

Comment: x @Mohamed: You mean, with $a, b, x_0, y_0$ as variables too? Definitely not convex since the set of $(x,y)$ is a slice of the 6-dimensional thing (setting $a=b=x_0=y_0=1$, for example), and a slice through a convex set is itself convex.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry but i'm new to that, i mean if $x$ and $y$ are 2 elements of $R^6$ vector.
$x_o, y_o, a, b, n$ are constants

Comment: x @Mohamed: The points $(a,b,_0,y_0,x,y)=(1,1,1,1,0,1)$ and $(a,b,_0,y_0,x,y)=(1,1,1,1,2,1)$ are both in the set, but the point halfway between them, $(a,b,_0,y_0,x,y)=(1,1,1,1,1,1)$, is not. Thus the set is not convex.

Comment: I think it is somewhat likely that you intended to write $\le1$ instead of $\ge1$ in the inequality, in which case the (two-dimensional) question of convexity becomes more interesting.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Actually i'm trying to solve an optimization problem with collision avoidance constraint by forming Superellipse centered at the obstacle position $(x_o,y_o)$ , $a,b,n$ form the safety distance. The problem is under $R^6$ as the object has surge, sway and yaw velocities, (x,y) for the position and $\psi$ for the orientation

Comment: Well, that is clearly not convex.

Comment: any suggestions to convert that to a convex one.